# changing the intensity of lighten/darken on bitmaps using PorterDuffXfermode in the Android Paint class

Tags: java, android, graphics, shader, paint

Ok my orignal question has changed. How do i change the intensity of how something like this is effected?

```
    DayToNight.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
```

in my dream world it would have worked like this

```
    DayToNight.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN(10)));
```

the 10 being a level of intensity.

---

An example would be if I had a flickering candle, when the candle burns bright I want the bitmaps I am drawing to the screen to retain their origanol color and brightness, when it flickers I want the bitmaps to be almost blacked out, and I want to darken the Bitmaps as the light dims.

I have equations, timers and all that figured out, just not how to actually apply it to change the color/brightness. 
Maybe burning the images is what im looking for?
I just want to change the lightness lol.

I feel like using paint.setShader might be a solution, but the information in this area is pretty limited from what i have been able to find. Any help would be appreciated.

edit: to be crystal clear, i am looking for a way to lighten/darken bitmaps as I draw them to the canvas

Comment: possibly something in here Paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.LIGHTEN)); even if so, how would i change the value of the lightening/darkening

Comment: It is amazing how I searched for hours and came up with nothing and now I am starting to figure it out... Thank goodness to the good people who post exaples of what does what

http://vollnixx.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/android-porterduffxfermode-examples/

Comment: how do you adjust the darkness intensity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These two approaches may solve your problem:

1. Put a dark rectangle behind your bitmap and set the Bitmap's
   opacity.
2. Use ColorFilter on your Paint when you draw the bitmap. To darken your bitmap use a semi-transparent black color

Comment: paint = new Paint();
          ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(0xFF222222, 0x00000000);
          paint.setColorFilter(filter);

Comment: if your bitmap has some transparent regions using a simple rectangle won't work because you will see it underneath. instead you can use both approaches and first draw a bitmap with LightingColorFilter(0xFF000000, 0x00000000) and then the same bitmap normally

Comment: The method mentioned by WIllJBD is great, works perfectly, you can even adjust the darkness levels.

Comment: @Soham how to adjust the darkness channels?

Comment: @MetaSnarf did u find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have used a kind of trick to remove the black line.In my erase button, I have set the color to white, instead of using XferMode.. It works and looks good..

```
if(erase){
paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
}
```