# Android, changing the lightness/darkness of a bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-view

I need to change the Lightness/Darkenss of bitmaps by varying degrees, at various times. How would I do this?

I am drawing theBitmaps to the canvas in a custom view. I Would like to think there is some way of doing this in the Paint Class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing the intensity of lighten/darken on bitmaps using PorterDuffXfermode in the Android Paint class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174583/changing-the-intensity-of-lighten-darken-on-bitmaps-using-porterduffxfermode-in)

Comment: Close, the first one was how/if I could do it with  PorterDuffXfermode, this one is just how to do it at all... as I discovered PorterDuffXfermode isnt going to be what I need I dont think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look into the [Paint.setColorFilter(ColorFilter filter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setColorFilter%28android.graphics.ColorFilter%29) method, and [LightingColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LightingColorFilter.html).

With the right values on the LightingColorFilter, you should be able to get the effect you are after.